# Discord Py - Music commands on a heroku hosted Bot

Tags: python, heroku, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to host my Discord Bot online now permanently. It hasn't changed much, although all the Voice channel (Musik commands) don't work anymore.

My requirements.txt file includes:
discord
,youtube_dl
,ffmpeg

On the Build log it does install them without any problems and the Bot soon goes online on the logs.
For your interest: I use Github to push my code to Heroku (it's connected to Github).

```
global voice
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)

    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()


    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
            queues.clear()
    except PermissionError:
        return

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'quiet': True,
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])

    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            name = file
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")

    def my_after(error):
        coro = voice.disconnect()
        for file in os.listdir("./"):
            if file.endswith(".mp3"):
                os.remove("song.mp3")
        fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, client.loop)
        try:
            fut.result()
        except:
            pass

    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('song.mp3'), after=my_after)
    voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(voice.source)
    voice.source.volume = 0.10
```

Above is just an example code, how one of my music commands looks like.

Here are all my imports to make it work on my local PC

```
import discord
import random
import asyncio
import youtube_dl
import os
import shutil
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions
from discord.ext.commands import Bot as BotBase
from discord.utils import get
```

I am aware that youtube_dl and ffmpegPCMAudio download and save the audio file (as in the code) in a Queue folder. But how can I realized/transfer that over to Heroku to make it executable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Buildpacks

First, you need to have 4 buildpacks on Heroku to make sure everything will work (`Your APP > Settings > Buildpacks`).

- heroku/python
- https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt.git
- https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git
- https://github.com/xrisk/heroku-opus.git

And check if you have all of these in your **requirements.txt**:

- pip
- youtube_dl
- discord.py[voice]
- ffmpeg
- PyNaCl

### Your Code

Add this to your code.

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.util

find_opus = ctypes.util.find_library('opus')
discord.opus.load_opus(find_opus)
```

### If it's still not working...

If you tried everything you can give this a try:

Make a new file called **Aptfile** (the same way you made file **Procfile**, so in CMD: `echo>Aptfile`. Then paste this inside:

```
libopus0
git
libopus-dev
libssl-dev
libffi-dev
libsodium-dev
:repo:ppa:mc3man/xerus-media -y
```

Comment: Wow it really worked with the buildpacks and the requirements - thank you so much!

Side note: the https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt.git buildpack is not necessary in order to work (it failed when i had it and removed it, then pushed it again)

Comment: Although i have a skip command and it says:
"discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: Already playing audio"

Answer (score 0):

Under the settings tab of Heroku, add the following buildpacks

- `https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git`
- `https://github.com/kitcast/buildpack-ffmpeg.git`
- `https://github.com/alevfalse/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg.git`
- `https://github.com/Crazycatz00/heroku-buildpack-libopus.git`
- `https://github.com/guilherme-otran/heroku-buildpack-ffprobe.git`

---

#### After that, it should look something like this

[image]

Re-deploy your bot, and see it it works

Comment: Sadly it didn't. It installed some components but it didn't change. I realized there was a link pasted twice and has to type it from the pic - no problem. 

Should i remove the ffmpeg from the *requirements.txt* ?

Comment: Yes you don't need ffmpeg in requirements.txt. I didn't realize I pasted a link twice, one of those two links is meant to be different. I've edited it now and replaced the other one with `https://github.com/alevfalse/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg.git`. Do the same then re-deploy and then see if it works this time.

Comment: Nope. The ffmpeg is removed from the requirements.txt and all the build packs are included. Didn't work